# setting of GRUB for two Linux distributions installed to two separate hard disks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I installed a second hard disk to my laptop so that I can test on new Linux distribution without trashing my working one.

I did the following:

1. Installed Linux Mint 15 to my first drive `sda` and use it as my working linux
2. Installed Linux Mint 16 to my second drive `sdb` and test it
3. I used `sudo update-grub` when boot to `sda` so that I can dual boot the two distributions
4. since Linux Mint 15 is no longer supported, I did my backup, cloned `sdb` to `sda` using Clonzilla
5. I want to use the `sudo update-grub` trick again so that I can dual boot both linux mint 16 distributions at `sda` and `sdb`.

I went to step 5, but things don't go as expected, if I plugged `sdb` into my laptop, it automatically boot to `sdb`, no matter which distribution I choose.

How should I adjust GRUB?

#### update 01

I have extracted my GRUB info using `boot-repair` and can be accessed via: http://paste2.org/NG99V4Fs

Comment: I'm not very sure, but do you need grub in both the HDs? How was it with Mint 15, in both? ..just curious to know.

Comment: @rusty both `sda` and `sdb` have mint 16

Comment: what did `sudo update-grub` say?